# How do I get the currently selected element in NSDatePicker?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsdatepicker

I'm using an `NSDatePicker` view for my project. The stock date picker is [not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269043/nsdatepicker-misbehaving-with-arrow-keys). Therefore, I have subclassed `NSDatePicker`  and am trying to handle keyboard events myself. These date pickers are placed in a table view.

[image]

Question: How do I detect the currently selected element (hour or minute) in my date picker?

Answer (score -2):

Access to single cells is only available through private methods. As an alternative, you may build your own NSDatePicker mimicking control without subclassing.

What is the ultimate goal anyway?

Comment: I am trying to customise the behaviour of the date picker. Increment seconds in steps of 5 when a key is pressed, for example. For that reason, it would be useful to know which element is selected when the arrow keys are pressed.